# how can you show a "no result found" after filtering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter

how can you show a "no result found" after filtering?

```
const searchItems = (searchValue) => {
    setSearchInput(searchValue)
    if (searchInput !== '') {
        const filteredData = APIData.filter((post) => {
            return Object.values(post).join('').toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase())
        })
        setFilteredResults(filteredData)
    }
    else{
        setFilteredResults(APIData)
    }
}
```

I returned the filtered data but I didn't know how to return a "no result found" if the user types wrong data!

**This is the text Input**

```
<OutlinedInput 
                className="SearchInput"
                placeholder='Search...'
                onChange={(e) => searchItems(e.target.value)}
                endAdornment={
                    <InputAdornment>
                    <SearchIcon />
                    </InputAdornment>
                }
            />
```

I'm using

```
{searchInput.length > 0 ? () : ()}
```

Comment: `{searchInput.length > 0 ? () : ('no data')}`

Answer (score 0):

You should check your `filteredData` after you recive the data.

```
if (searchInput !== '') {
    const filteredData = APIData.filter((post) => {
        return Object.values(post).join('').toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase())
    })
    if(filteredData){
        setFilteredResults(filteredData);
    }else{
       console.log("no result found");
    }
}
else{
    setFilteredResults(APIData)
}
```

Or check if your response contains some type you are looking for like

```
if (!isNumber(filteredData.id) && filteredData.id === 0) {
    console.log("no result found");
}
```

You can find some examples over here https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter